# Want to test turn server - With puppeteer and https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Tags: puppeteer

What I want to do:
I want to test my stun and turn server by using puppeteer to use the google webrtc example implementations automatically.

Problem: 
Using puppeteer returns different local addresses and no IPv6.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath:
          'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
        args: [
          "--no-sandbox"
        ]
      });

      const pages = await browser.pages();
      const page = pages[0];
      await page.goto('https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/');
    })();
```

With Puppeteer:

````
0.010   rtp host    3103129966  udp d5f4bf78-64bb-4f9c-9ae4-ee0a4c3892de.local  58262   126 | 30 | 255
0.011   rtp host    2094226564  udp e657b779-3563-4753-aa3f-a533494f02aa.local  58263   126 | 40 | 255
0.070   rtp srflx   842163049   udp 80.142.xxx.xxx  58262   100 | 30 | 255
```

Without puppeteer:
```
0.003   rtp host    3103129966  udp 192.168.2.111   59612   126 | 30 | 255
0.003   rtp host    2094226564  udp [2003:f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx] 59613   126 | 40 | 255
0.062   rtp srflx   842163049   udp 80.142.xxx.xxxx 59612   100 | 30 | 255
```

Do I miss a config parameter could not find anything so far.
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
TRY/ERROR different parameters
```
      "--enforce-webrtc-ip-permission-check",
      "--force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy",
      "--webrtc-stun-probe-trial",
      "--enable-webrtc-stun-origin
```

thx
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into similar problems as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/rR5QANwvF0Y/Q1khPJh6AAAJ).
In pupeeter you never called getUserMedia so host candidates will be obfuscated using mdns. In the browser you did at some point and that information is persisted.

--disable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns will disable mdns but note that the host candidates you get are irrelevant to answering the question whether the TURN server works (which it does not in your case as there is no relay candidate)

Comment: Thx you very much. But even if I have a stun and turn server with IPv6 support. Im not able to get a IPv6 relay nor srflx with puppeteer.